# terminating process with an integer

Tags: java, arrays

My task is getting the numbers and printing them with their occurrences.
I must terminate the process with the integer `0` but I am doing it with the string `x`.

This is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class yasf{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] numbers = new int[101];
        int num;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a number between 0-100 inclusive. x terminates:");
        String numString = scan.nextLine();

        // The input treminated with x;
        while (!numString.equalsIgnoreCase("x")) {
            num = Integer.parseInt(numString);
            numbers[num] = numbers[num] + 1;
            System.out.println("Enter a number between 0-100 inclusive. x terminates:");
            numString = scan.nextLine();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
        if (numbers[i] != 0 && numbers[i] == 1)
            System.out.println(i + ": " + numbers[i] + " time");
        else if (numbers[i] > 1 && numbers[i] != 0)
            System.out.println(i + ": " + numbers[i] + " times");
        else
            System.out.print("");
    }

}
```

}

How can i do this?

Comment: I'm not very clear on what your issue is? are you trying to change your terminator value to "0"?

Comment: Your terminator value should be 0, but you also want to accept 0 as a valid input?

Comment: the code is working.but i want to terminate the process with the integer '0'. in this code the termination key is 'x'.

Comment: yes,kevin you're right. there is a mistake :) i must edit that too.

Comment: Assuming your mistake is about zero being valid input. Why can't you just swap !numString.equalsIgnoreCase("x") with !numString.equalsIgnoreCase("0") ?

Comment: kevin thank you so much,how couldn't i see that, i forced my self 'there must be string',so i couldn't think there can be ''0'' too. thank you again :)

Answer (score 1):

If you still want to accept "0" as valid input, remove the first instance of

```
System.out.println("Enter a number between 0-100 inclusive. x terminates:");
String numString = scan.nextLine();
```

and make your main while loop look something like this

```
do{
  System.out.println("Enter a number between 0-100 inclusive. x terminates:");
  numString = scan.nextLine();
  num = Integer.parseInt(numString);
  numbers[num] = numbers[num]+1;
}while (!numString.equalsIgnoreCase("0"));
```